# Is a 3 GB USB enough for installing Ubuntu?

Tags: usb

This is my first time installing a Linux distro so I don't know much about the prerequisites. I am currently using Windows 7 and would like to install and use Ubuntu alongside Windows. I wanted to ask whether I can use a 3 GB USB stick for the installation? As far as I know the iso is 1.5 GB, so should it be fine?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said what Ubuntu you are talking about, also whether or not you are talking about desktop, server, IoT appliance software or other, and each has different requirements, let alone release requirements (ie. later ISOs contain more drivers and are thus larger). The desktop for example suggests 25GB, and modern ISOs require a 4GB before installation (are you asking about install to thumb-drive?? OR just the ISO written to thumb-drive to later install on hdd/ssd/other-device?  The Ubuntu ISO I downloaded yesterday is 2.6GB in size for example so I'd not expect it to fit (needs 4GB)

Comment: Thanks for replying; I want it installed on my desktop and would like to create bootable usb for the installation. So I guess 3 GB isn't enough, right?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you mean is your USB large enough to hold the Ubuntu ISO so that you can install it on your computer? If that is your question, the answer is, "Yes, but just barely. It's a 2.5 GB ISO which should be not much larger when written to a device." If your question is if you can install the OS in just 3 GB of space, the answer is not with Ubuntu.

Comment: You haven't provided any specific details of what release, or ISO you are intending to use. It is my understanding all will fit on 4GB, however you cannot install to 4GB.  Some ISOs are smaller than others, and I still use 2GB thumb-drives for some, but require 4GB for others.  (*I'm assuming `dd` or like write of ISO to thumb-drive, and not install onto thumb-drive*)

Comment: if you use the *mini.iso* (netboot) it'll fit on a 384MB thumb-drive (maybe smaller) as far as I recall, however that's a specific ISO that downloads everything it needs.  *ie. there is no actual answer to your question as it'll depend on what ISO you're intending to use & write, with the answer varying on which you need to use, as we have been given no specifics*

Comment: I guess I'm not ready for the installation, and should research more about the specifics. Thanks for helping everyone!

Comment: The following link may help you: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre - 'Prerequisites'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/pre)

Comment: Off-topic, but "*I am currently using Windows 7*" is a massive, massive red flag.  Unless your PC is 100% disconnected from the internet and will never be connected, the question is not if you'll be hacked and lose everything, but when.  Move to Windows 10 immediately; or wipe it completely and install Linux over the top.  Whatever you do, your job today, this minute, should be moving off Windows 7.

Comment: This is a pointless question.  You can fit linux into almost anything.  Whether it will be useful for you or not depends entirely on what you intend to do with it.  Is 3GB big enough for an Ubuntu installation ***to do what***?  To run a database server?  To browse facebook?  To work as an automation controller? To do software development?  Or just a toy install to bosh about on?

Comment: There are a lot of comments on this question indicating the lack of details required for a good answer, so why isn't the question closed as such?

Comment: Please, why are you Asking here first, rather than at your chosen Linux or Ubuntu publisher's site? If you did go there first, what was missing?

Answer (score 15):

Yes and potentially No.

A *netboot* or *mini.iso* will fit on a 384MB thumb-drive/install media (*possibly smaller depending on release should you have a thumb-drive that small still lying around*).

The last Ubuntu desktop ISO I downloaded (*groovy* yesterday) was 2.5GB and I used a 4GB thumb-drive to write that onto.

But the size varies on release, and that was a *groovy* desktop ISO will be larger than older ISOs that contain less or no *closed-source* drivers, plus released (*non-development*) ISOs include less diagnostic/development libraries useful in crash reporting which exist only on development ISOs.

However my most common thumb-drives I use are still 2GB as many ISOs will fit on them.

The thumb-drive size required will depend on

- the release you want (*closed source* blobs aren't included all releases)
- the version you want server? desktop? or other?
- the flavor you want?  (*some don't include closed source blobs*)
- plus the ISO you choose (options exist)

We have no specifics, so cannot provide a specific answer.

Comment: if it's not clear, the *closed source* blobs include nvidia et.al.

Answer (score 10):

### Ubuntu Install Quick Start

The current Ubuntu 20.04 install disk is 2.7GB.

Download Ubuntu 20.04 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Start with a USB of at least 3GB formatted FAT32.

If using Windows, download Rufus. https://rufus.ie/

Double click the Rufus .exe file. (No need to install).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Select USB Device and Ubuntu ISO file for Boot Selection.

Confirm Persistent partition size is 0 MB.

Select `START`

When Rufus is done you can use USB to install Ubuntu to BIOS or UEFI machine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes 3 GB USB drive will fit for Live Ubuntu ISO. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 (1.8 GB disk image) in multi boot with windows with 3.66 GB USB drive. If you use a mini ISO then the you even don't need a 3 GB ISO, and old USB drive about 386MB is enough. Though if you want to create persistent USB stick, then to create the persistent partition file, you need a USB drive greater than 4 GB.

Comment: "Fit the live ISO" is not quite the same as installing it, though. I think persistence would be needed in order to match the OP's expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's not necessarily so straightforward. Most live images use a compressed root filesystem, which is much smaller than an uncompressed root. The obvious solution is to install less packages, replace the desktop environment with a lighter one, etc., but this is not always a reasonable solution. That's why you'll most likely need to use a compressed root too.

Some numbers: A minimal installation of most linux distros with a Desktop Environment and very common packages (office, music, video, browser, etc.) weighs around 3-5 GB. Because CDs only have a capacity of 650-700 MB, and binaries and text files (both which are the bulk of those 3-5 GB) compress *very* well, all live images of the distributions that I know of use a compressed root.

The easiest way to have a compressed root filesystem is to use btrfs with compression enabled (but beware that btrfs is somewhat less stable, especially if the system hangs or experiences sudden power loss). See this thread for ideas about how to install on btrfs with compression: [Trick installer to use btrfs root with compression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6197/trick-installer-to-use-btrfs-root-with-compression)

Another way is to do it the way live images work, but this is much more involved: In many distros, live images have the root mounted as an overlayfs, which combines two mountpoints, with the bottom layer a squashfs image (a filesystem designed to compress very well files to fit distros onto a CD), and an tmpfs upper layer (a volatile, in-RAM filesystem) which holds the changes to the system.

Comment: "I've stopped using ISOs and Ubuntu a long time ago" -> I'd be curious, what did you switch to?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon , I'm using Arch almost exclusively nowadays. Usually I just drop a root image where I need it, a bootloader if needed and I'm done. It's more convenient for me and also much easier if the system does not have optical drives, can't boot off usb or is headless (my laptop and phones are 1&2, my workstation is 1&3, all my Raspberry Pis are 1,2&3).

Comment: @Nmath , my solution is to do the thing ISOs do: compress the root filesystem.

Comment: @mostanes thanks for the details and welcome to this Q&A site. I happen to also use headless Raspberry Pis (as servers), and deeper embedded systems, too, where I fiddle with the GNU toolchain linker scripts (no joke). That said, given the OP mentions using Windows, they most probably need an "ordinary" setup. Also your answer explains *how* a live-CD or live-USB works, which is interesting but not what the OP asked. You'll find plenty of other questions where your detailed knowledge will be useful to others and appreciated, just try to stick to the questions asked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try to edit to match a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were originally asking, but I really like the "Live" USB drives @Wasif_Hasan mentioned above. You can try your 3GB drive first, it might fit. Otherwise use a larger drive and create a "Live" boot drive. You can boot to Ubuntu without actually repartitioning your Windows machine for dual boot. This way you can test and see if all your hardware is supported (such as laptop camera). Also you can get a taste of Ubuntu before you take the larger step. This tutorial should help:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

You will get a slower experience, but if you like what you see there is a link on the "Live" desktop to do a full side-by-side desktop install (or replace Windows completely on that machine - but see below).

What ever you do, I suggests backing up all your data on your Windows 7 machine first. Good practice even if you are doing a major Windows upgrade. If your hardware and budget allow, I would also recommend moving to Windows 10 ASAP (as in one of the comments above), or just move to a new Windows 10 machine and completely replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu. I've always found a second machine to be more useful than a dual boot (although that's how I started).