# I want to install Kubuntu 20 on a Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu

I have downloaded Kubuntu 20.04 start up on a usb stick. It won't boot from the usb, so I restarted to go to bios to check the selected boot drive. Ubuntu keeps booting up and I can't get to the bios. I've tried using f12, f10, f2 and escape many times each. Once I got a blank screen for awhile, then ubuntu booted back up again. Is there another way to install Kubuntu? I don't know how to write code; but I have copied and pasted code in a terminal.

Comment: I don't know what box (make/model) you are using, but I have boxes (esp. laptops) that wouldn't go into BIOS/UEFI setup on f12/f10 or f2, as they require a different key to be very quickly pressed as stated in the very limited literature that came with it on purchase. You may not be entering BIOS/UEFI setup because you're not pressing the required key for your make & model device.  *eg. one annoying devices requires me to press & hold a key with it off, then turn it on OR if i continue to hold that key it'll turn on by itself into UEFI setup mode; ie. do whatever you device requires*

Comment: Did you just put Kubuntu on a USB stick or did you install it as a Live USB? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259731/is-a-3-gb-usb-enough-for-installing-ubuntu/1259750#1259750